# create a .tar file of all latest files in the directories

Tags: files, scripts, sort, timestamp

I am in a directory A. This has a lot of sub directories B, C, D. Each sub directories will have a list of files. I need to create a `.tar` file of all the latest file in each subdirectory.

Example:

```
Directory A :
  Sub directories: B, C, D

Files in directory B : b/1, b/2, b/3
Files in directory C : c/4, c/5, c/6
Files in directory D : d/7, d/8, d/9
```

I need a `.tar` file that contains (b/1, c/4, d/7). 1, 4, 7 are the latest files in the directories. I tried to do that using the `find` and `sort -r`. But this prints all the files in the directories.

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A python solution to do the job completely. It creates a `tar.gz` file from the latest files of all sub directories of a given directory.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time
import tarfile

files_dir = "/path/to/directory/with/subdirectories"
targeted_file = "/path/to/latest_files.tar.gz"

latest_files = []
# get the latest files of all sub directories
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(files_dir):
    for dr in dirs:
        dr = root+"/"+dr
        filelist = []
        for item in os.listdir(dr):
            file = dr+"/"+item
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                filelist.append((file, os.stat(file).st_mtime))
        filelist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        if len(filelist) != 0:
            latest_files.append(filelist[-1][0])
# write to latest_files.tar.gz
tar = tarfile.open(targeted_file, "w:gz")
for file in latest_files:
    tar.add(file, arcname = file.split("/")[-1])
tar.close()
```

Copy the script into an empty file, set in the head section of the script the directory, containing the sub directories (`files_dir =`), and the path to the `tar.gz` file (`targeted_file =`), and save it as `get_latest.py`.

Run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/get_latest.py
```

#### What it does

The script first lists all (sub-) directories. Within the sub directories, it lists the files, sorts them by modification date and adds the latest ones to the "master" list, to be included in the compressed file.

---

#### To set the number of versions to include

To give the answer a more universal character, below a version of the script in which you can set the numbers of (latest) versions to include in the compressed file. If the number of set versions (`versions =`) exceeds the actual number of files in a folder, all files are included.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time
import tarfile

files_dir = "/path/to/directory/with/subdirectories"
targeted_file = "/path/to/latest_files.tar.gz"
versions = 1

latest_files = []
# get the latest files of subdirectories
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(files_dir):
    for dr in dirs:
        dr = root+"/"+dr
        filelist = []
        for item in os.listdir(dr):
            file = dr+"/"+item
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                filelist.append((file, os.stat(file).st_mtime))
        filelist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        if len(filelist) != 0:
            for item in filelist[-versions:]:
                latest_files.append(item[0])
# write to latest_files.tar.gz
tar = tarfile.open(targeted_file, "w:gz")
for file in latest_files:
    tar.add(file, arcname = file.split("/")[-1])
tar.close()
```

Comment: Pefect. But I need one small modification. when I untar the files, the entire directory structure is maintained. I need only the files to be tarred. The file names will be unique.

Comment: @Raj edited my answer, just adding `arcname = file.split("/")[-1]` did the job; now only the file (name) is in the `tar.gz` file, not its containing directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

"Latest" is hard to define. I think you can use `find` in two ways here:

1. List all files modified later than another file:

   ```
   find . -type f -newer b/1
   ```
2. List all files modified less than `x` minutes ago (say 10):

   ```
   find . -type f -mmin -10
   ```

Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
ls -tl | sed -n 2p
```

it should  returns the name and details of the newest file in a directory .